# How to show BAr graph rather than line graph in High Stoch Chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I am trying to use High Stock Chart but rather than showing a line graph in it I want to show bar graph is there a possibility to do same

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/basic-line/)

My end requirement is to make a graph like this[image]

```
Will it involve some additional CSS
```

I need to show time slider at bottom as mentioned in screenshot
On Change of time interval on slider my graph will change

Please suggest on same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After playing around with the chart I found the following solution which can be seen in the demo below:

```
$('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {

            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },

            rangeSelector: {
                allButtonsEnabled: true,
                selected: 2
            },
```

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/330zm96y/1/)

The formatting is not the same as your end result but you should be able to play with the styling and ranges to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.
But i need time slider also as mwentioned in screenshot

Comment: How about navigator, it is similar to your slider.

Comment: Even Navigator is Fine

Comment: @SebastianBochan No I am sorry for my previous comment Navigator I cant use as Data that I have to show cant be connected together as It belong to different category.

Comment: The categories are not supported in the highstock,so so you need to use datetime of xAxis.